# ¿como obtener los elementos de un array en un $request en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, array

ya que no consigo hacer una trasaccion a la Base de datos desde laravel, esta transacción son varios DB::insert los valores que van a tomar en cuenta son los del array, pero cada vez que intento obtener estos valores me dice que la variable $criterio tiene parametros indefinidos y no se que hacer para obtener esos valores.
Quiero aclarar que estoy usando laravel + vue, le pase el array por axios y no estoy usando migraciones ya que tengo una base de datos ya armada con mas de 40 tablas.

aquí esta el código

```
    public function crearFormula(Request $request){
        $variables = $request->all();
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            foreach($variables as $criterio){
                $id_var = $criterio->id_variable;
                $pesos = $criterio->peso;
                $id_prod = $criterio->id_productor;
                $tipo = $criterio->tipoEval;
                
                DB::insert("insert into 
                evaluacion_criterio(id_productor,id_variable,fecha_inicio,peso,tipopor) 
                    values('$id_prod',
                    '$id_var',
                    current_date,
                    '$pesos','$tipo')");
                }
            DB::commit();
            return 'ok';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

al hacer var_dump a criterio me dio:

```
array(5) { 
     ["id"]=> int(0) 
     ["peso"]=> string(3) "100" 
     ["id_variable"]=> string(1) "1" 
     ["tipoEval"]=> string(10) "renovacion" 
     ["id_productor"]=> int(0) 
}
```

y varaibles en si me da:

```
 array(2) { 
     [0]=> array(5) { 
             ["id"]=> int(0) 
             ["peso"]=> string(3) "100" 
             ["id_variable"]=> string(1) "1" 
             ["tipoEval"]=> string(10) "renovacion" 
             ["id_productor"]=> int(0) 
             } 
     [1]=> array(5) { 
             ["id"]=> int(1) 
             ["id_variable"]=> string(1) "8" 
             ["peso"]=> string(2) "60" 
             ["tipoEval"]=> string(10) "renovacion" 
             ["id_productor"]=> int(0) 
             } 
     }
```

Comment: Haz un debug de `$criterio` y dinos qué datos hay. Debes verificar lo que estás recibiendo.

Comment: bueno yo veo los errores a traves de inspeccionar elemento en chrome en la seccion de Network me salen todos lo archivos que a cargado la aplicacion y al final sale uno nuevo referente a la operacion que quiero hacer y cuando lo selecciono  en el archivo dice el error: ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id_variable' of non-object.

Comment: Vaz un `var_dump($criterio);` dentro del `foreach` y agrega un extracto del objeto en la pregunta. Parece que no te está devolviendo un objeto realmente.

Comment: ya lo coloque, espero que sirva de algo

Comment: Creo que ya tienes una buena respuesta de parte de @BetaM. Estabas recibiendo un array, no un objeto y la forma de leer los arrays es distinta a la de los objetos: `$array["clave"]` no `$array->clave`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea:

```
gettype($request->all());
```

Te retorna un array y no un objeto, dicho de paso este array es de una sola fila por lo que si decides seguir usando esta línea:

```
 $variables = $request->all();
```

Entonces al momento de asignar valores, en lugar de hacer esto:

```
$id_var = $criterio->id_variable;
```

Deberás indicar la clave entre corchetes para acceder al valor como parte de un array y no de un objeto así:

```
    $id_var = $criterio["id_variable"];
```

Por otro lado pudieras construir tu solución así:

- Toma los valores directo del objeto `$request` asignalos a variables y no lo iteres
- Usa el método table para indicar en que entidad almacenarás los valores
- Remueve el acceso al método `all()` para que puedas acceder a los datos de las claves con la sintaxis de `->` desde el objeto `request`
- En el método insert pasa los valores en formato de array

Código:

```
<?php 

public function crearFormula(Request $request)
    {

        $id_var  = $request->id_variable;
        $pesos   = $request->peso;
        $id_prod = $request->id_productor;
        $tipo    = $request->tipoEval;

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try { 
                
            DB::table('evaluacion_criterio')->insert(
                ['id_productor' => $id_prod],
                ['id_variable'  => $id_var],
                ['fecha_inicio' => 'current_date'],
                ['peso' => $pesos],
                ['tipopor' => $tipo]
            );

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
    }
```

**Referencia**

- [Query builder (*insert*)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts)
- [Request class](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#accessing-the-request)